# How do I define the units when creating a rectangle around points in arcpy?

Tags: arcgis, arcpy

So, I am trying to create rectangles around points on a map that is 50meters wide and 500 meters wide. I used the following code, which worked, but the units are off so the rectangles are enormous (see photo).

The map projection is WGS 1984, so the units are decimal degrees. So, I figured that the reason why the scale was off was because the length and widths were in meters, not decimal degrees. So, I calculated the difference in lat and lon 50 meters east of a point and 500m south and used that as length and width. The code went through, but the output didn't display any features (even though there was an attribute table). I figured that maybe it doesn't like decimals but it worked for w=0.1 and h=1, until I turned the layer off and then back on again. Now that layer doesn't display anymore.

I am at a loss, I don't know what I am doing wrong. Here is the code I used.

```
inFeatures = "potentialpoint.shp"
outFeatureClass = "rectanglestest.shp"
rectangleWidth= 50
rectangleHeight = 500

# create a new feature class to hold the rectangles
arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("D:\OceanWind2023\DepletionExperiments", outFeatureClass, "POLYGON")

# loop through each point and create a rectangle around it
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(inFeatures, ["SHAPE@XY"]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        x, y = row[0]
        array = arcpy.Array([arcpy.Point(x - rectangleWidth / 2.0, y - rectangleHeight / 2.0),
                             arcpy.Point(x - rectangleWidth / 2.0, y + rectangleHeight / 2.0),
                             arcpy.Point(x + rectangleWidth / 2.0, y + rectangleHeight / 2.0),
                             arcpy.Point(x + rectangleWidth / 2.0, y - rectangleHeight / 2.0)])
        polygon = arcpy.Polygon(array)
        with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(outFeatureClass, ["SHAPE@"]) as insertCursor:
            insertCursor.insertRow([polygon])
```

Answer (score 0):

pointFromAngleAndDistance will give you distance in spatial reference units of measure.
Acting on the XY coordinates are in the coordinate system in your case decimal degrees so you are changing X by 25 and Y by 250 degrees.

```
pnt = row[0]
array = arcpy.Array(
pnt.pointFromAngleAndDistance(
       84.3, 251.247), #NE point

pnt.pointFromAngleAndDistance(
      95.7, 251.247), #NW point

pnt.pointFromAngleAndDistance(
      263.4, 251.247), #SW point

pnt.pointFromAngleAndDistance(
       275.7, 251.247)) #SE point
```